# How to update date/time per line generated by command

Tags: awk, timestamp

Sounds easy but I didn't manage though ...

I'd like to prefix the output of a command (which is returning several lines) with the date/time the line is generated. To simplify here, I use the ls as an example. The real command is too lengthy.

The `ls` command says:

```
root@gan:~/test# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_c
```

This was as far as I got ...

```
root@gan:~/test# ls -l | awk -v var=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") '{ print var " " $0 }'
20150923-102310 total 0
20150923-102310 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_a
20150923-102310 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_b
20150923-102310 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 08:54 file_c
```

As it is now, the date/time is the one when the *command is executed*, not updated per line `ls` command generates.

How can I modify this so that every line `ls` command generates is preceeded by the date/time the line is generated (as opposed to the date/time the command executed)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `date` result in variable, you could execute the `date` command for each line, then you will get different datetime.

```
ls -l |awk -v cmd="date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N" '{cmd|getline d; print d,$0;close(cmd)} '
```

In above line, you can see, the `cmd` variable, is not the result of `date` command, (not `$(...)`). It is just the command line string.

And I added `%N` (nano seconds) in the pattern, so that we can see the different timestamp.

if I test it on my `/tmp/test` dir, the output is:

```
kent$  ls -l |awk -v cmd="date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N" '{cmd|getline d; print d,$0;close(cmd)} '
20150923-112448877540265 total 4
20150923-112448884685628 -rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent  49 Sep 22 12:31 f
20150923-112448891512367 -rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Sep 18 12:54 fao
20150923-112448898479494 -rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Sep 18 12:54 fbo
20150923-112448904315207 -rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Sep 18 12:54 fco
20150923-112448912507549 drwxr-xr-x 6 kent kent 260 Sep 22 17:18 javassist/
```